# Can't delete or rename original file after resizing

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

This function return an resized and centered image, and I execute it calling an url `thumb.aspx?image=test.jpg&width=100&height=50` the problem is that **after the execution**, **I can't rename or delete the original file from server.**

```
  <%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing" %>
    <script language="C#" runat="server">
    void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
      try {
        Response.Cache.VaryByParams["Image;Width;Height;needToFill"] = true;
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        System.Collections.Hashtable imageOutputFormatsTable = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
        imageOutputFormatsTable.Add(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif.Guid, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        imageOutputFormatsTable.Add(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        imageOutputFormatsTable.Add(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp.Guid, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        imageOutputFormatsTable.Add(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff.Guid, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        imageOutputFormatsTable.Add(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png.Guid, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        string imageLocation = Server.MapPath(Request.QueryString["Image"]);
        int Width = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Width"]);
        int Height = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Height"]);
        System.Drawing.Bitmap image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(imageLocation);
        int sourceWidth = image.Width;
        int sourceHeight = image.Height;
        int sourceX = 0;
        int sourceY = 0;
        double destX = 0;
        double destY = 0;
        double nScale = 0;
        double nScaleW = 0;
        double nScaleH = 0;
        bool needToFill=true;
        nScaleW = ((double)Width / (double)sourceWidth);
        nScaleH = ((double)Height / (double)sourceHeight);

        if (Request.QueryString["needToFill"] != null) {
            needToFill = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.QueryString["needToFill"]);
        }

        if (!needToFill) {
            nScale = Math.Min(nScaleH, nScaleW);
        } else {
            nScale = Math.Max(nScaleH, nScaleW);
            destY = (Height - sourceHeight * nScale) / 2;
            destX = (Width - sourceWidth * nScale) / 2;
        }

        if (nScale > 1) nScale = 1;

        int destWidth = (int)Math.Round(sourceWidth * nScale);
        int destHeight = (int)Math.Round(sourceHeight * nScale);

        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmPhoto = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(destWidth + (int)Math.Round(2 * destX), destHeight + (int)Math.Round(2 * destY));
        bmPhoto.SetResolution(72, 72);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat outputFormat = (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat)imageOutputFormatsTable[image.RawFormat.Guid];
        ApplicationException ex= new ApplicationException(string.Format("destWidth:{0}, destX:{1}, destHeight:{2}, desxtY:{3}, Width:{4}, Height:{5}", destWidth, destX, destHeight, destY, Width, Height));
        System.Drawing.Graphics grPhoto = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
        Rectangle to =  new System.Drawing.Rectangle((int)Math.Round(destX), (int)Math.Round(destY), destWidth, destHeight);
        Rectangle from = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight);
        grPhoto.DrawImage(image, to, from, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        bmPhoto.Save(Response.OutputStream, outputFormat);
        bmPhoto.Dispose();
        grPhoto.Dispose();
      }
      catch (Exception ex){
        System.IO.StreamWriter sw=null;
        try{
            sw=new System.IO.StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("error.txt"),true);
            sw.WriteLine("Error : " + ex.Message + " processing " + Request.QueryString["Image"]);
        }    
        catch{}     
        finally{sw.Close();}
        Response.Redirect("thumberror.gif");
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: `image` doesn't look like it's being disposed. I'd recommend using a `using` statement to make resource management more clear.

Comment: move everything out of this control that doesn't have to do with reading the request and returning the response.  move the image resizing logic into its own class.  Then you can test the class without launching the web server.

Comment: @vcsjones your comment is the answer ;)

Comment: Always dispose GDI resources resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`image` doesn't look like it's being disposed. I'd recommend using a using statement to make resource management more clear.

A [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) allows placing something in a scope, and when the scope is left, it gets `Dispose` called on it. For example:

```
using(var image = new Bitmap(imageLocation))
{
    //Use image here
} //image will be disposed here
```

Comment: what do you mean saying "using statement"?

Comment: Tried, but can't understand how :)